# Why cant my React App handle links to one of its routes?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, express, react-router

**Edit: For anyone coming here from Google, here is a TLDR: The reason for this "issue" is that React uses client side rendering. A quick solution is to use the HashRouter component, an SEO friendly solution is to use server side rendering(SSR). I switched to using [NextJS](https://nextjs.org/), an SSR React framework, and my concern is resolved. Pages refresh like normal, and favorites work as intended. Thanks to all in the comments.**

**Original Question:**

I've tried to find the answer to this but maybe i'm not googling well enough. So I have a react app with multiple routes, one of the routes is `/reset`, I have routing set up in the App.tsx like so:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';

class App extends Component<IAppProps, IAppState> {
    constructor(props: IAppProps) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            loggedin: "false",
            user: {
                username: "",
                email: ""

            }
        };
    }

    <Router>
                    <nav className="topnav">
                        <ul>
                            <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
                            <li><Link to="/about">About Us</Link></li>
                            <li><Link to="/faq">FAQ</Link></li>
                            <li><Link to="/login">Login</Link></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/">
                            <Home
                                text="This text was passed in as a prop"
                            />
                        </Route>
                        <Route path="/login">
                            <Login
                                changeHandler={this.updateLoginInput}
                            />
                        </Route>
                        <Route path="/register">
                            <Register
                                formSubmit={null}
                            />
                        </Route>
                        <Route path="/forgotpassword">
                            <ForgotPassword
                                stateSetter={this.handleChange}
                            />
                        </Route>
                        <Route path="/reset">
                            <Home/>
                        </Route>
                </Route>
            </Switch>
    </Router>
```

Sorry for the bad indenting, the editor doesn't like tabs.

The links work fine but, when ever i manually type in the address bar `localhost:3000/reset` it just keeps spinning and eventually times out. Same with every other route in fact. I need this to work because im sending a password reset email that will contain a link to use, and currently it just keeps spinning when the link is clicked. What if someone were to favorite a route on my page like `mysite.com/page1`? It would keep spinning and then eventually time out.

I've tried to add a route on the server side with `app.get()` and a `response.redirect()` and redirect to the reset route, but Chrome blocked it as an unsafe redirect.

Does this functionality not work on localhost or is there something else i'm doing wrong?

Comment: To be able to help you with your problem we'd need access to your project. The routing you config you setup looks fine so the problem might be elsewhere. If it's possible, post your project to Github and share the link.

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually

Comment: why are again closing tag here  `<Route path="/reset">
                            <Home/>
                        />` ?

Comment: @sanfalero I saw that link and it seems to address my issue directly, however it was answered 4 years ago. Is there an alternative solution to the Isomorphic app that is suggested in the answer?

Comment: @KireetiGanisetti My bad i apologize, i edited it after i pasted it in

Comment: Perhaps it is something else as it should work on localhost. I wasn't able to repro it in a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-http-un7sq?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js&theme=dark).